# How to create a pdf form using pdfrw using the pdf basics using the "/Annots" dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pdfrw

I would like to create a pdf form button and other widgets in pdf using python but donot want to us the form generation modules available with pyupdf, borb etc..

I want to create a "Annot" pdf dictionary structure and add all the relevant details of the form button in to it.
Request help from the team for a head start

Comment: Would request to programatically add button widget using python to make it click go to another page link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`

`borb` allows you to manipulate PDF documents both in a high-level and low-level fashion.

You can build forms by adding `LayoutElement` objects that inherit from `FormField`.

But you can just manipulate the underlying dictionaries of the PDF and do everything yourself. Or even do a combination of both.

Use an existing `LayoutElement` to already do most of the heavy lifting for you, and then tweak the final stuff yourself.

An example of doing everything yourself can be found here:
https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples?tab=readme-ov-file#85-creating-a-document-using-low-level-syntax

Although this example doesn't go into detail about forms, it does show you how to manipulate the dictionaries that make up the PDF.

You can also find a copy of the PDF spec in the `borb` repository.

Comment: Thanks Joris for sharing.. will look in to it..